# Formatear fecha

Tags: angular, primeng

Tengo mi interface:

```
export interface Period {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  periodDate: Date;
}
```

.html

```
<p-calendar formControlName="periodDate" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
```

y mi componente

```
save(data: any) : Observable<any> {
  console.log(data.periodDate)
```

en la consola me devuelve

```
Mon Mar 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)
```

pero yo quiero que me devuelva (

```
Mon Mar 07 00:00:00 CET 2022
```

Comment: A lo mejor te sirve: [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No encontré un pipe que sea igual al que pides, pero algo similar, sí:

```html
<p-calendar formControlName="periodDate" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy">
  {{periodDate | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, y'}} 
  <!-- R: Monday, March 07, 2022 -->
</p-calendar>
```